# Krita: How to make a particular layer appear (be visible) from a particular frame onwards?

Tags: animation, krita, layer-composition

I am using Krita 4.2.6 on Linux / Ubuntu and making an animation.

I have a layer, on which there is a .png image. This layer should be invisible in the first 30 frames of my animation.
How can I make it visible from the 30-th frame onwards only?

Comment: I'm not certain this is a graphic design question.

Comment: Hi Alex. Flagging comments is meant to be used for problematic content (i.e. spam or rudeness). Mayo's comment is not problematic, even if you disagree with it. If you can formulate a kind and to-the-point response, please do so via comment.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to animation curves docker
2. Add keyframe (should result in an opacity keyframe) to whatever frame number you want
3. Change the opacity to either 100 (visible) or 0 (nonvisible)
4. Click the hold constant icon button (important or else it will interpolate, i.e. it will make the visibility change over time rather than like an on/switch)
5. Whenever you'd like to switch the visibility repeat step 3